# Where can I find a list of common phrases?

Tags: phrases

I'm not so good at english, and I would ask if someone knows a website that lists the most used english ways to say, like for example, "eat the bullet" or "with a grain of salt".

I've done some research about it, but the only thing I got is Urban Dictionary, but unfortunately it's not easy to find the phrases; it would be great to have a vocabulary of "ready phrases" (for poor-english people like me:-)

Comment: The *most used english way to say, like for example, "eat the bullet"* is ***bite** the bullet*. This is an Off Topic request for resources, but I've run out of closevotes for the day.

Comment: Not really a question for this forum, but here you go - http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/

Comment: I'd avoid Urban Dictionary generally; a great many entries are jokes, the outpourings of bizarre psychosexual fixations, or otherwise just plain misleading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Eat the bullet means killing yourself by putting a gun in your mouth.  Bite the bullet means "bear with it".

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/  - this site is great and is often used as a reference on this site.

Comment: @David: All I can say is if I was out on a stag night where my "non-native speaker" friend was fretting about whether he really should get married in the morning, and if the last thing he said to me was *"I guess I'll just eat the bullet"*, I'd be expecting him to show up the next day. I certainly wouldn't be so worried I'd put in a call to The Samaritans on his behalf. You may find that expression used in a gangster movie, I suppose, but it's hardly a usage that should be relevant to a *learner*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hence the danger of non-native speakers using stock idioms.  (See my answer below.)  But, yes, I don't think you need to take away all of the sharp objects or lock him in a padded room until the wedding takes place.

Comment: @JonHanna "Outpourings of bizarre psychosexual fixations..."  I've been laughing for 2 minutes straight at that!

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the situation you hypothesise, I would take how well-armed they were into account, just in case.

Comment: @Jon: It was only a hypothesis (I think I'm getting a bit too old to be invited out on stag nights! :) But I prefer my drinking buddies to have at most one arm on each shoulder, given that some of them tend to be of the [Instant Asshole: Just Add Alcohol](http://shirtshovel.com/alcohol-instantasshole.shtml) persuasion. Guns and booze don't make for a good cocktail.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in my experience, while guns and booze don't make for a good cocktail, swords (unless ritual or ceremonial) and booze make for literally bad cocktails, viz. a particular mixture of buckfast, cheap cider, whiskey and undisclosed ingredients referred to as "battle brew" that won't so much put hairs on your chest, as on your tongue.

Comment: What I was looking for are exactly "common idioms", thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you're looking for are called idioms or colloquialisms. Searching with those terms might help. That said here are a couple lists of examples to help you out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English-language_idioms

http://www.idiomsite.com/

http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idioms_alphalistsA-Z.htm

Heck, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=english+idioms+list+for+learning+the+language

Answer (score 2):

There is a good website devoted to phrases in [British and American English here](http://www.phrases.org.uk).

That said, I would recommend avoiding "ready made phrases".  In the vocabulary of language learners, they tend to sound forced, and worse, unintentionally comical.

It is important to be able to understand the idioms used by native speakers, but I would generally discourage their use until your language skills have improved to the point where they occur organically.

Best of luck!